# How to get the element before last?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

In Protractor, there is the `.first()` and `.last()` methods available on  `ElementArrayFinder`:

```
var elements = element.all(by.css(".myclass"));

elements.last();
elements.first();
```

But, how to get the element *just before the last one* (penultimate) without knowing how many elements are there in total?

Comment: Ah, assumed you were using jQuery with the $, did not look at the tags.

Comment: @epascarello ah, sorry for the confusion. Protractor has `$$` shortcut as well. Replaced the shortcut with the full expression to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [negative indexing](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) to get the elements from the end by index:

> Negative indices are wrapped (i.e. -i means ith element from last)

```
elements.get(-2);  // the element before last
```