# Angular is not defined on Ionic 2 using protractor 2

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, protractor

According to [Protractor Angular 2 Failed: unknown error: angular is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201691/protractor-angular-2-failed-unknown-error-angular-is-not-defined) angular selectors by.model are not supported.

I also went to http://www.protractortest.org/#/ and I noticed that seems that no change was made to fix this.

How can I set an input text using protractor and Angular 2?

**EDIT**

I can select my  by making this:

```
let myelement: ElementFinder = element(by.css('.text-input'));
```

But I have several inputs on my html page. How can I have the 4th ion-input, per example?

Comment: Could you show how your input looks like in HTML? Thanks.

Comment: Angular-seed did setup protractor, maybe it helps https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/src/client/app/%2Bhome/home.component.e2e-spec.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I have several inputs on my html page. How can I have the 4th ion-input, per example?

You can issue [`element.all()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and use [`.get(index)`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) to access an element by index:

```
let myelement: ElementFinder = element.all(by.css('.text-input')).get(3);  
myelement.sendKeys("text");
```

Note that we use `3` since indexing is 0-based.

You can also make use of a [convenient shortcut](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$$) for CSS selectors:

```
let myelement: ElementFinder = $$('.text-input').get(3);
myelement.sendKeys("text");
```

FYI, negative indexing is also supported in case you want to get elements from the other end:

- [How to get the element before last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934045/how-to-get-the-element-before-last)

Comment: The second one run perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Protractor [allows you to use the element.all function](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#finding-multiple-elements) which returns an array of objects.

So for your particular example you could do something like this put inside of your test case:

```
    element.all(by.css('.text-input')).then(function(elements) {
       elements[3].sendKeys('some text')
    });
```